# How to decode messages in MM2 offset sync topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

In reference to the offset sync topic covered in [KIP-382](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0#KIP382:MirrorMaker2.0-Walkthrough:RunningMirrorMaker2.0) that maintains the cluster-to-cluster offset mapping, while consuming the messages from `mm2-offset-syncs.target.internal` found them to be serialized.

1. Is there a way the output can be deserialized so its understandable using the kafka command line consumer?

   ```
    ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:xxxx --topic mm2-offset-syncs.dest.internal --from-beginning
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `OffsetSyncFormatter` to deserialize the content of your offset syncs topics. For example:

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
  --topic mm2-offset-syncs.target.internal \
  --formatter org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.formatters.OffsetSyncFormatter \
  --from-beginning
```

The more details, see [KIP-597: MirrorMaker2 internal topics Formatters](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-597%3A+MirrorMaker2+internal+topics+Formatters)